# Adjust SKSpriteNode and SKPhysicsBody with specific image.png or image.jpg

Tags: iphone, swift, xcode6-beta6

I am developing a game with a character with some particular shape, I am creating an `SKSpriteNode` object with this line:

```
let rockl:SKSpriteNode = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.redColor(), size: CGSize(width: newweight*ancho/16, height: alto/5))
```

I am assigning a physical body with this line:

```
rockl.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: pipeBotton.size)
```

and I am assigning the image with this line:

```
rockl.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "character.png")
rockl.texture.filteringMode = SKTextureFilteringMode.Nearest
```

But the borders are not the same to the border of the image. how can I adjust the object to the image? or whats is the technique to create a custom shape?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to create your `physicsBody` with [`SKPhyiscsBody(texture, size)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsBody_Ref/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKPhysicsBody/bodyWithTexture:size:). From the docs:

> Use this method when your sprite has a shape that you want replicated
>   in its physics body. The texture is scaled to the new size and then
>   analyzed. A new physics body is created that includes all of the
>   texels in the texture that have a nonzero alpha value. The shape of
>   this body attempts to strike a good balance between performance and
>   accuracy. For example, fine details may be ignored if keeping them
>   would cause a significant performance penalty.

You can also create your `SKSpriteNode` with a texture directly instead of creating it with a flat color first:

```
let rocklTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "character.png")
rocklTexture.filteringMode = SKTextureFilteringMode.Nearest

let rocklSize = CGSize(width: newweight*ancho/16, height: alto/5)

let rockl = SKSpriteNode(texture: rocklTexture, size: rocklSize)
rockl.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: rocklTexture, size: rocklSize)
```